# printing directory with simple ls and grep command Linux

Tags: linux, shell, grep, ls

So I have this command `ls -al -R | grep libbpf.h` and it just act dump print

```
 -rw-r--r-- 1 root root   53107 جنوری  27 12:05 libbpf.h
```

I also need the exact subdirectories that contain this file is there a way I can use the above command with some option for grep or ls so it also prints some thining like

```
 -rw-r--r-- 1 root root ./libbpf/src/include/libbpf.h  53107 جنوری  27 12:05 libbpf.h
```

so I only knows the the libbpf.h does exists in somewhere from root directory recursively searching just give me the path, does any one knows this

Comment: I know this command works but looking for grep and ls `bpf# find . -wholename '*libbpf.h'`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

you can use find command

```
find "$(pwd -P)" -type f -name "libbpf.h" -ls
```

if you want only paths

```
find "$(pwd -P)" -type f -name "libbpf.h"
or
find . -type f -name "libbpf.h" -exec realpath {} \;
```

Comment: can u please tell what is -P flag in referring to current directory?

Comment: @user786 Use `man pwd`. This will give you the manual entry describing what `pwd` is and its options. In this case `-P - avoid all symlinks`

Comment: as already answered -P  print the physical directory, without any symbolic links